# How would I interface with the Linux terminal (bash for windows) using windows command prompt?

Tags: bash, command-line, cmd, terminal, command-prompt

I just recently found out about using bash in windows. I had alot of fun installing linux programs onto my windows computer using bash and wondered how I would be able to run an automatic script so I dont have to export my display everytime I open bash. 
I used to write scripts for cmd called batch scripting and I would be able to do everything cmd could do. Now that I have access to bash, I want to script a program that connects useful pieces of cmd with useful pieces of bash but I Can't find any results telling me how to call bash commands from cmd. Thank you - Zak Kaioken

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. Although they run on the the OS (same kernel), they are pretty separate.

Comment: According to [this site](https://www.howtogeek.com/262086/how-to-run-linux-commands-from-outside-the-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) you can run `bash` commands inside `cmd` using `bash -c ...`. Is there anything else you want to do?

Comment: Realistically I just want to automate the setup process of getting gui programs working on my pc, and using .batch files and .sh files are not working for me.